# Skip to next task in a single threaded ExecutorSerivce?

Tags: java, multithreading

I am considering an implementation of an ExecutorService to run a series of tasks. I plan to use the internal queue to have a few tasks waiting for their turn to run. Is there some way to interrupt the task (the Runnable) that is currently running in an ExecutorService thread, and keep the thread alive to run the next task? Or is only possible to call `.shutdown()` and then create a new ExecutorService?

I have found [this](https://dzone.com/articles/interrupting-executor-tasks) and wanted to know if there are any other solutions.

Comment: If you can get the identity of the worker thread (Hint: have each task can call `Thread.currentThread()` and stash the result in a global variable), then interrupting it is trivial. If each of your tasks cleanly handles the interruption and returns, then problem solved.  If something goes wrong and the worker thread dies, then I _think_ that the `ExecutorService` will create a new worker to take its place. (But I'm not 100% certain, so you might want to experiment before taking my advice.)

Comment: Beware though! I've just set you up for a race condition if you care _which_ task gets interrupted: If the worker is running task A when your code decides to abort it, task A potentially could reach its natural end, and the worker could start on task B before the interruption actually gets delivered.

Comment: Have you tried changing your tasks so they respond to interrupts by cleanly exiting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of interfering with the threads you may want to have a `Task class` (that extends or wraps the `Runnable`) which implements an interrupt mechanism (e.g. a `boolean` flag).

When you execute your task you need to check this flag periodically and if it is set, the task should stop what it is doing. You might want to return a specific result at this point, that tells your code that the task was cancelled succesfully.

If a user now decides that he no longer requires the results from this task,
you will have to set this flag. However the task might have already completed at this point of time so you still need to deal with the cases where the result already exists but the user does no longer care about it.

---

An interrupt on a thread level does not guarantee that the thread stops working. This will only work if the thread is in a state where it can receive an `interrupt`.

Also you should not interfere with the Threads of the `ExecutorSerivce` directly, as you might unintentionally stop a different task or stop the `ExecutorSerivce` from working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to kill that task and continue with the next one? If it is a question of times you can define that the threads that are taking longer than you declared in the method that executes them are automatically canceled. E.g:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor.invokeAll(Arrays.asList(new Task()), 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Timeout of 60 seconds.
executor.shutdown();
```

If any of the threads takes longer than 60 seconds it will throw a `cancellation.Exception()` that you must catch

Comment: I would want to kill the task because the User has decided that that task is no longer useful to run, and I don't want to waste the cycles (or have the effects present of) finishing it.